# How can I determine the correct encoding?

Tags: java

I was trying to print some chinese characters as below but this won't work. I suppose there should be some sort of encoding to be done. Can you please help mo on this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String myString = "奥妙洗衣粉";
    System.out.println(myString);

   // Output in eclipse: Some characters cannot be mapped using Cp1252 character encoding.
   // Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported 
   // by the Cp1252 character encoding.
}
```

**EDIT:** How can I do it (change/apply the encoding) programatically before printing the string?

Comment: Check the workspace encoding in eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default encoding in file output:

```
new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
```

---

Another problem, the compiler can read only ASCII characters (but the JVM could read others as well). This means, strings cannot be built from foreign characters. The proper way to do it, determine the character's Unicode - 4 char hexadecimal code - and build like this:

```
String myString = "\u3b12\uc2d4hello"
```

This creates a string with the first char as the code 3b12 (escaped with the `\u` Unicode character) + c2d4 + hello.

Here's my output:

```
㬒싔hello
```

Comment: so what is 'fileName' here?

Comment: Where it should be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

Windows-1252 character encoding does not support the characters in your code. Use UTF-8.

Comment: how can I do it programatically before printing the string?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything in the Java itself. Java has support for UTF built into its strings by default.

Comment: Change the encoding of your *files*. Eclipse provides a way to do this for all files in a project.

Comment: Suppose I'm not using eclipse and I just want to apply a particular encoding, say "Big5", how would it be?

Answer (score 0):

the console in eclipse does not support those characters by default.
here is a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/) on that

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the eclipse console encoding is not utf-8.

you should change the console encoding,

i hope this link help you : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-eclipse-console/